# What to use to clear paint a few pieces of brass?

Tags: paint, metal

I want to paint a few pieces of brass, with some kind of clear paint/primer. Removing the pieces and spray painting would be tedious, so I am looking for an option where a brush would be used. I've searched online, and so far have come up with a few things, namely clear metal primer (if it does exist), shellac and epoxy resin.

- How would clear metal primer (if it does exist), shellac and epoxy resin work to paint a few small pieces of brass?
- What would be the best/a relatively durable paint/primer to use on brass?

Regards.

Comment: I am not an expert on panting brass as I don't think I have ever seen real brass painted but I have painted a lot of steel/similar metals with clear-coat spray paint made for auto bodies and works awesome.  I suggest you find a few auto body spray paints and read their directions - to see if it will work on brass.  Might be able to just email them via website if you can't find it.

Comment: I have some diving "treasures" that after many hours of polishing I coated with a clear shellac. The bright shiny color last for years but when I moved to my latest home my prize piece started to yellow or darken. Not sure if this is an environmental change or ? but will strip it and polish again then seal, before I I sealed this piece I was polshing every 3-4 months.

Comment: Why not polish and wax? I don't know that there are many transparent coatings that themselves do not discolor. What is the nature of the objects?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that crystal clear **enamel** or brass lacquer (actually not a lacquer- it's polyurethane) may be what you are after (enamel connotes painting metal). Please pardon the product recommendation, but Rustoleum Crystal Clear Enamel works pretty good, but Mohawk Brass Lacquer is specifically for the job.

Spraying it on makes a physical difference- it is more durable... aerosol is closer to being a vapor deposition. The trick is to use 2 light coats. But I suppose that you could use any old brush-on polyurethane; for what it's worth, I think an oil based one might be a little more durable.

Don't use shellac, as it is actually made for penetrating wood, so it won't work on metal (although what people call shellac and lacquer are often acrylics or polyurethanes). There are a variety of qualities regarding epoxy. Some epoxies will become cloudy or yellow with age, so if you don't want that, aim for something that is used more for finishing rather than sticking things together. Also, be aware that an epoxy might be more difficult to remove. Overall, I think epoxy might not be the best choice for you.